# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "spotify:" - error: "(null)"

Tags: ios, localhost, spotify, info.plist

Not sure if this is true , but from what I've read, people say this issue only occurs on the Xcode simulator so you you must test on an actual device. The problem with this is my current server is a local node server at `http://localhost:3000`, and my iOS device can not access this server.

1) Is there a way to give my iOS device access to the local server on my device?

2) Why am I getting this error when running the simulator?

I have put the following in my info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>spotify</string>
</array>
```

Comment: The error simply means that the Spotify app isn't installed. That is why you must test on a real device since you can't install the Spotify app on the Simulator.

Comment: how do I get around this if i want to test authentication on the simulator? not possible?

Comment: just give your computer a static IP Address and make sure your device is connected to the same network.   then you change your url to http://192.168.1.100:3000.  You may also need to add some parameters when starting your node server to allow other connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To test on the device - replace the localhost address with your local network IP address. The local network address usually looks like 192.168.xxx.xxx and can be found in network settings.

2) The error simply means that the Spotify app isn't installed. Give your computer a static IP address or you must test on an actual device.